# When offering a choice of two items and selecting both is an option, is it better to use checkboxes or radio buttons?

Tags: forms, webforms

Two options shown here. We can use both types. Both have pros & cons. Which one is better?

[image: Radio buttons (Customer, Item, Both) or Checkboxes (Customer, Item)]

Comment: Please, give us some more details on what problem your are trying to solve with this "Options". I can only say that their are not equal, and you can't just switch between them, beacause they gives different meaning and opportunities to users. It very depends on what you want to accomplish. (have you seen that? http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/)

Comment: where is the 'None' RadioButton?

Comment: The second option offers the opportunity to not select any item at all, with the first one this is not possible. The question is: do you want this?

Comment: **tl;dr** > mutually exclusive options = radio buttons, multiple choice = check boxes

Comment: aw, it is like trick questions in high school all over again, please never use the "All of the Above" radio...

Comment: Checkboxes. Definetwly checkboxes. It's the whole purpose and difference between checkboxes and radiobuttons. You know - normally radiobuttons appear in groups and you can only select one. They're called radiobuttons because of the old radios which had big keys you can press and when youbpress them every other key goes back to normal stage. I still got some of these Radios

Comment: @GeertImmerzeel, Sorry I missed to mention about this field, it should be mandatory, There is no "NONE" option here. we need to mention anyone for tax purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting from 2 options where it can be either or both](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76187/selecting-from-2-options-where-it-can-be-either-or-both)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### Go with checkboxes for consistency

- **Radio buttons** usually express **mutually exclusive options** (*EITHER this OR that*), so giving an option that includes an item but excludes it at the same time **won't be consistent**.
  Contrary to checkboxes, it's  expected to *select exactly 1 item, neither less nor more*.
- **Checkboxes** are used **to select several items** (*this AND that*) which is the case. Also they let you select **none**.
  Bear in mind that it might happen that you have to add a *new option* and if you use radio buttons, then "both" will be meaningless and you'll have to redesign this control (also remember *users hate changes unless they're great improvements*).   With checkboxes that's not a problem.
- **"Both" option has more cognitive load since it doesn't express something by itself**, it's a reference to another items, so the *state is not directly showed*. Additionally you are adding +1 element to the UI.
  A way to improve it would be to explicitly name the label "Customer + Item" or "All", similarly as the case of the classic single choice questions, where you can find options like "*Answer D*: "All previous answers are correct" or "A and C are correct".
  But anyway, if the answers are not mutually exclusive, you could add an "All" checkbox as a shortcut for users, *without losing visibility of the selection state*. There's a similar approach used in table-like components, like [Gmail Inbox](http://images.pcworld.com/images/article/2012/07/gmail20is20unimportant-11383765.jpg), where you have a "select all" checkbox.
- There are use cases when they both could fit the requirements, each one having its pros and cons, then you really need some user testing to see which generates less confusion. See [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/67609/adding-a-none-of-the-above-option-to-a-list-of-checkboxes/) for a very special use case.

Comment: Instead of saying "*this XOR that*", you can say "*either this or that*" (or "*or this, or that*").

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Right. I have the engineering student syndrome.

Comment: Don't worry. I am a programmer and I'm used to that term. But many people aren't, and they will be looking at it with a weird face, trying to figure out "what the *fudge* is xor!?". But be happy, you have improved your answer!

Comment: Radio buttons also convey that you *must* select something, whereas checkboxes do not.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to force the user to make an active choice (even if that choice is "neither option"), then initially unchecked checkboxes is a poor choice. But on the whole, I agree with this.

Comment: '"Both" label has more cognitive load' - is that always true? If the "both" option is interpreted as a kind of a "I'll just take whatever is available" option, it can be processed without the need to decide, think about, or possibly even fully understand the other options, as a kind of an "easy way out". That sounds more like it could also present *less* of a cognitive load depending on the context.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You're talking about an 'any' option. In this case it's a bit ambiguous, but I think the answer is referring to an 'all' option. In which case, adding more and more options increases the amount of thinking required to determine if this is the right action for you.

Comment: @Prinsig: Yes, I meant an *all* option. If I simply want to get everything that is available (e.g.: total price is negligible anyway; I want to download now and process/delete later; I have enough disk space and want to try every feature; etc.), I can simply select *both/all* and do not have to think about the other items at all => less cognitive load.

Comment: @jelumalai If my answer (or another) was useful-enough to get to your solution, consider to accept an answer. Here it shows how http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Comment: @O.R.Mapper First "both" is not a familiar in the web at all, that adds cognitive load per se. " The requeriments could be very different depending on what are you selecting, it's not the same having 10 options than 2. It's not the same if the users are in contact with the system in a daily basis or if they use it ocassionally. Having only two options doesn't require an additional option if it's just part of a form or filter. If it's a form it add cognitive load because you have to evaluate the 3 options instead of 2. Imaging this, you read the first option, you checked it, you read ....

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ... the second, you checked, and then there's a 3rd option that say both, so now previous selection is useless!
If the controls work as filters, as in e-commerce websites, and you have a lot of options, the default filter will be no filter or in other words "All checked" option. 
The thing here is as several users point out, both options presented in the OP doesn't doesn't have the same affordances, it lacks information so the answer given will tend to be more or less general.
Answering your question: it doesn't have to be always true, but for this very short option list, it is.

Answer (score 9):

Beside making the eligible options and combinations thereof explicit, as noted in various other answers, there may be another use case where the radio buttons are preferable:

If the options are conceptually independent of each other, and selecting both options just means a mere *addition* of options, two checkboxes are fine. However, if selecting both options means that the result will somehow *merge* the options, the three radio-buttons can be a better choice.

This is a "soft" definition, and there are certainly borderline cases. However, let me explain the subtle difference I see in two examples:

- When ordering something, I might be offered up to two gifts as a loyal customer of the online store. If I get two checkboxes that say "gift 1" and "gift 2", respectively, I expect to get two parcels if I check both checkboxes. On the other hand, if I have the choice between three radio-buttons "gift 1", "gift 2", and "both", and I select "both", I somehow expect to get one parcel that contains both gifts.
- When booking some holiday arrangement, checking both checkboxes "flight" and "hotel" implies to me that the travel site will book each of them independently, and I will get two separate tickets/vouchers. Selecting "both" among three radio-buttons "flight", "hotel", "both" implies to me that I will be getting a complete package that includes both a flight and a hotel.

As a concrete example, the travel website [Expedia](http://www.expedia.de) provides, for their "click&mix" packages, three mutually exclusive toggle buttons:

[image: Mutually exclusive toggle buttons: Flight + Hotel; Flight + Hotel + Rental Car; Flight + Rental Car]

- Flight + Hotel
- Flight + Hotel + Rental Car
- Flight + Rental Car

This reflects the fact selecting *Flight + Hotel + Rental Car* is not the same as booking *Flight + Hotel*, and then *Flight + Rental Car* (even if we ignore that this would leave us with two flights in this particular case). *Flight + Hotel + Rental Car* is a combined offer that only works for a common set of travellers and a common date range for the trip, and that is sold as a combined package.

---

A note about *None* being eligible: Even with the checkboxes, this is not usually a problem. *None* is a very special state whose invalidity in certain contexts can very intuitively be conveyed to users. When selecting items to order, hardly any user will be confused by the fact that selecting no items to order means they cannot continue the ordering process. Therefore, disabling the *Ok* button or showing an error message upon clicking *Ok* if no options are selected is not contrary to user expectations. Accordingly, whether or not *None* is a valid choice is only a secondary factor in the presented decision between checkboxes and radio-buttons.

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote, please?

Comment: I didn't vote, but I find your expectations about packaging very strange. And you don't point to any research indicating that anyone else shares your interpretation. (I get what you are trying to say, but your examples are really strained.)

Comment: @alexis: That's true, unfortunately, I could not yet find any research that has checked whether users perceive two checkboxes vs. 2 radiobuttons + a "both" radiobutton as subtly different or the same in the specific situation that the combination of the two options might be "more than the sum of its parts". I will update the answer if I come across something more conclusive in this respect.

Comment: I'm not too sure you will. Having a "both" radio button really goes against the concept of radio buttons (as many of the other answers say.) Can you even find any real-life cases where it's used this way? They would support your case.

Comment: @alexis: As I have tried to explain in my answer, in situations where the "both" radio button implies something else than the mere addition of the two other options, it actually seems to match the concept of radio buttons better than checkboxes. An (incidentally, travel-related) example can be seen on the travel website [Expedia](http://www.expedia.de/), which offers, for its "click&mix packages", three mutually exclusive toggle buttons labeled "flight + hotel", "flight + hotel + rental car", "flight + rental car". (The flight is always there, combined with hotel, rental car, or both.)

Comment: Your claim is clear. It will be more convincing if you add the expedia example to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the checkboxes are better.  The exception is when all of the below are true:

1. You have enough screen space to handle something like "Both Customer and Item", as well as having three radio buttons instead of two checkboxes
2. You are targeting users who are unfamiliar with web interfaces such that they won't naturally just click on both checkboxes, and even putting the phrase "click on all that apply, but you must click at least one" somewhere won't help.
3. "Neither" is not an option, and you want to make that fact explicit.

Note that the same discussion can be had if None is an option but Both is not.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where there are two or more items and it is legal to select any item by itself, and some but not all other combinations of items are valid, the question of whether to use radio buttons for all valid combinations of items, or whether to use check boxes but recognize that some states may not be valid, is something of a judgment call.  In most cases when there are three or more items, one approach will be clearly superior to the other (either because the radio button would entail too many choices, or the validity conditions for the checkboxes would be harder to understand than a list of valid combinations).  When there are exactly two items, either approach may be reasonable depending upon what else is going on with the form.

If both "None" and "Both" are valid combination, then the checkboxes are likely the better approach.  If "None" is not a valid combination and one is willing to accept that clicking a checkbox on a valid form may cause it to become invalid, checkboxes may still be better.  If it is necessary that a click on a valid form must leave it in a (potentially-changed) valid state, however, clicking the only checked item will create a somewhat awkward situation.  If X is initially checked and Y is initially unchecked, and the user wants X unchecked and Y checked, having X not do anything until after Y is checked would be awkward, but having X check Y would also be strange.  Having the click on X not visibly alter the state of the checkbox but set a flag so that clicking Y would turn off X might often achieve the desired behavior, but it would be strange.  Perhaps clicking X could "dim" the checkbox for a little while, and clicking Y while the checkbox is dim would uncheck it, but that would be rather unusual.

The checkbox situation works out a bit better if "none" is a valid choice but "both" isn't.  While user-interface guidelines may not particularly smile at such behavior, it is not uncommon for the act of clicking on a checkbox to automatically click off any checkboxes which would be incompatible with the new selection.  If the checkbox being clicked highlights itself for the duration of the click, all affected checkboxes should do likewise.  That behavior doesn't seem suitable for your present scenario, but it might be if the wording of the conditions was reversed.

Answer (score 1):

There are good answers and if you are still looking for alternatives:

Step 1: Display Customer and allow the user to ***Skip*** or ***Select***

Step 2: Display Item and allow the user to ***Skip*** or ***Select***

Order of display is purely driven by the context and that will also influence the ***usability***.

Displaying one after the other keeps the **Cognitive** **load** to the minimal with no choices to make.

To keep the user **NOT** **guessing**, the second option could be displayed as grayed out but ***transparent*** (similar to how modal windows are expected to allow the user to allow user to still retain the view of the underlying screen content).

[Progressive disclosure](http://uxpatterns.org/affordances/progressive-disclosure/) technique is pretty apt fit for this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and attached image, you are providing options to the user. And I believe for this kind of requirement, Checkbox is more appropriate and rather intuitive to the user. And visually, checking something relates more to options.

Radio buttons, on the other hand, are better suited for toggling requirements (turning on/off something). IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It depends on the requirements.

Between the two screenshots you provided, there's VERY different functionality. For the radiobuttons, one (and only one) must and can be selected. But for the checkboxes, none or more can be selected.

Assuming the user must pick at least one option, the radiobuttons would be better. Assuming the user is free to pick no option, the checkboxes would be better.

As for general guidelines, radiobuttons should ideally only be used when there's conflicting choices. In the case of your first example, this is not correct. I would advise to re-write it two a simple small form:

```
Customer: yes - no
Item: yes - no
```

If picking the checkboxes, your current example is fine.

Note that it never hurts to give the user some visual feedback! Whichever you pick (radio or check), below the form you can have a small summary of the picked choices.

Example for checkboxes:

```
Wrap my order in giftpaper: yes
Include the order confirmation with the package: no
Sent me updates on the status of my order: yes
```

> You have chosen to wrap your order in giftpaper and wish to receive
>   updates on the order status. We will not include the order
>   confirmation with the package.

A solution like this would be a bit more work to implement, but if done right (read: with proper sentence construction), it will make it a lot easier for the average user/customer to validate their choices.

To make it easier to read, you should list all positives first followed by all negatives. Using them interchangeably might confuse the user/customer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have option a, b, or both. That takes up either 3 lines with option 1, or 2 with option 2. No big difference, you might say?

Lets say in 6 months, you add another item to the list, say retailer, because your site is expanding and you are adding 3rd party retailers.

Now, using option 1, you have 7 lines - Customer;retailer;item;customer and retailer;customer and item;retailer and item;all 3. Whereas with option 2 you increase from 2 lines to 3.

Then, you decide to add reviews to your site and want to search on those. Option 2 is going to become 4 lines instead of 3. Option 1 is now some number I can't be bothered to calculate.

If you are deciding between two roughly equal optionswhy not not choose the option that can scale, on the chance that you might eventually need to.

Answer (score 0):

@rewobs has given valuable insights on why and how one should select the controls.

Already much has been written and said about the choices and if I have to pick, I would go with the "check boxes". For the reason they will select either ONE or ALL the options available, based on your parameters ("All of the Above") (I consider it as not a good option to include)

> You can also use controls which will be useful in terms of saving space, innovative interaction and ease of use. Try **Select 2**
>
> It offers improved and enhanced versions of traditional check boxes control.
>
> Have a [look at the examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) which can invoke some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox is more preferrable in simple terms easy for user to select.You can also go for a ***dropdown list box*** with three options Customer,Item and Both too .